# Cursor Value Error While Working With Cursor

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-fragmentactivity, android-cursor

I'm working with Fragment and Im trying to load my data in recyclerview and for that I have created a LoodRoomData method in which I have coded for getting my data , but the problem is while making it possible I'm getting an error which I have described within an image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mScEC.jpg)

I have provided Fragmenthome loadroomdata method, model class for room , database code of creating room table along with sqlite database class loadroom data method

```
//Method for fetching data 
private void LoadRoomData()
    {
        Cursor cursor= dbHelper_room_visitor.GetRoomData();
        roomItems.clear();
        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            int idd =cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper_ROOM_VISITOR.ROOM_ID));
            String ro_number=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper_ROOM_VISITOR.ROOM_NUMBER_KEY));
            String ow_name= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper_ROOM_VISITOR.ROOM_OWNER_NAME_KEY));
            roomItems.add(new RoomItem(idd,ro_number,ow_name));
        }
```

```
//ROOM_TABLE

    private static final String ROOM_TABLE_NAME = "ROOM_TABLE";

    public static final String ROOM_ID = "_RID";

    public static final String ROOM_NUMBER_KEY ="ROOM_NUMBER";

    public static final String ROOM_OWNER_NAME_KEY = "ROOM_OWNER_NAME";

    private static final String CREATE_ROOM_TABLE =

            "CREATE TABLE " +ROOM_TABLE_NAME +"("+

                    ROOM_ID+ "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"+

                    ROOM_NUMBER_KEY + "TEXT NOT NULL,"+

                    ROOM_OWNER_NAME_KEY + "TEXT NOT NULL,"+

                    "UNIQUE (" + ROOM_NUMBER_KEY + "," + ROOM_OWNER_NAME_KEY + ")" +

                    ");";

    private static final String DROP_ROOM_TABLE ="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ ROOM_TABLE_NAME;

    private static final String SELECT_ROOM_TABLE ="SELEC> T> FROM "+ ROOM_TABLE_NAME;
```

```
//Sqlite method for fetching 

//LOAD_ROOM_DATA

    Cursor GetRoomData()

    {

        SQLiteDatabase database=this.getReadableDatabase();

        return database.rawQuery(SELECT_ROOM_TABLE,null);

    }
```

```
//Model class 
public class RoomItem extends AppCompatActivity{

    public RoomItem(String classname, String subjectname)

    {

        this.classname = classname;

        this.subjectname = subjectname;

    }

    public RoomItem(long cid, String classname, String subjectname)

    {

        this.cid=cid;

        this.classname = classname;

        this.subjectname = subjectname;

    }

    private long cid;

    public long getCid()

    {

        return cid;

    }

    public void setCid(int cid)

    {

        this.cid = cid;

    }

   private String classname;

    public String getClassname()

    {

        return classname;

    }

    public void setClassname(String classname)

    {

        this.classname = classname;

    }

    private String subjectname;

    public String getSubjectname()

    {

        return subjectname;

    }

    public void setSubjectname(String subjectname)

    {

        this.subjectname = subjectname;

    }

}
```

Basically the error is
'Value must be greater equals to 0 but getcolumnindex can be -1'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite JavaScript? Scala? SQL? forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.